# Nest.js + Casl conditional checking is not working

Tags: nestjs, casl

I have been learning Nest.js.
I integrated auth & authz with jwt + casl following the docs [nestjs casl integration](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization#advanced-implementing-a-policiesguard)

[github repo](https://github.com/AxelReid/nestjs-practice/blob/main/src/ability/ability.factory.ts)

Everything is working except **casl conditional checking**:

```
can(Action.Update, User, { id: user.id })
```

here, even though `id` isn't equal to `user.id`, it's not restricting the action

Comment: i ended up using `nest-casl` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-casl

Comment: If you restrict the example and specify values of user.id, I’ll be able to tell you why it doesn’t work in your case. Very likely another rule allows you update user

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi i'm currently using `nest-casl` package, for conditional checking with that package, a hook(which defines the data that is being compared against) should be defined https://github.com/getjerry/nest-casl?tab=readme-ov-file#advanced-usage

Should the same thing be defined with the `casl` itself or does it work out of box?

Answer (score 0):

**Is User a database model?** Because in that case it won't work.

This is because you must pass an instance of that class when you check the permissions, but that is not practical (imagine querying an specific user from the database every time you want to compare 'id').

In my case, I used a 'dto' that validates most of the User's properties. Make sure 'id' property is defined.

For example:

*UpdateUserDto*

```
export class UpdateUserDto {
id: string;
username: string;
profile_picture;
}
```

Now in your *user.service.ts*

```
/*Assuming you returned an 'user' object from an 'auth guard'*/
updateUser(updatedData: UpdateUserDto, user) {
const ability = this.caslFactory.createForUser(user);

if(!ability.can(Actions.update, updatedData)) throw new ForbiddenExceptionError('This user can't perform this kind of action')
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: so the data which is being compared against should be defined manually, like this https://github.com/getjerry/nest-casl?tab=readme-ov-file#advanced-usage?

Comment: EDIT: Yes, you have to create an instance with the data that is coming from the client. If I understood well [linlk](github.com/getjerry/nest-casl?tab=readme-ov-file#advanced-usage), you use a hook that queries the necessary data from the database in order to check permissions. This is okay, but it's up to you choosing a method that adapts better to your case.