# CASL condition matcher is not matching

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, authorization, casl

I have the following CASL ability factory:

```js
type Subjects =
  | InferSubjects<
      | typeof Post
      | typeof User
    >
  | 'all';

export type AppAbility = PureAbility<[Action, Subjects]>;

@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user: Partial<User>) {
    const { can, build } = new AbilityBuilder<PureAbility<[Action, Subjects]>>(
      PureAbility as AbilityClass<AppAbility>,
    );

    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      // Basic permissions for unverified users
      can(Action.Read, 'all');
      can([Action.Update, Action.Delete], User, { id: user.id });
    } else {
      // Verified user permissions
      can([Action.Create], Post);
      can([Action.Update, Action.Delete], Post, { authorId: user.id });
    }

    if (user.role === UserRole.MODERATOR) {
      // Additional permissions for moderators on top of verified user permissions
      can([Action.Update], Post);
    }

    if (user.role === UserRole.ADMIN) {
      // Admins can do anything, overriding all previous permissions
      can(Action.Manage, 'all');
    }

    return build({
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
      });
  }
}
```

However, while using only basic conditions `{ authorId: user.id }` (which I thought didn't need a custom conditionMatcher), it throws

```bash
You need to pass "conditionsMatcher" option in order to restrict access by conditions
```

I partially fixed by passing `conditionsMatcher: buildMongoQueryMatcher({})` into the `build()` function argument object as a property. Although the error is gone, now the condition is not being checked i.e. user can edit other users' posts.

Why could it happen?

---

I found a related thread (with no answers): [Nest.js + Casl conditional checking is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262259/nest-js-casl-conditional-checking-is-not-working)

In the comments, it's mentioned that the OP ended up using nest-casl instead. I hope there's a way without switching to another package.

---

**UPDATE:** According to the comment, I tried to change `PureAbility` to `Ability` but seems like `Ability` does not exist in the latest CASL version. Below is my try to use `createMongoAbility`, but the result is still the same.

```js
const conditionsMatcher = buildMongoQueryMatcher({ $ne, $nor, $eq }, { ne, nor, eq })

@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user: Partial<User>) {
    const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<PureAbility<[Action, Subjects]>>(
      // PureAbility as AbilityClass<AppAbility>,
      createMongoAbility
    );
    console.log({ userId: user.id })
    if (user.role === UserRole.USER && !user.emailVerified) {
      // Basic permissions for unverified users
      can(Action.Read, 'all');
      can([Action.Update, Action.Delete], User, { id: user.id });
    } else if (user.role === UserRole.USER) {
      // Verified user permissions
      can([Action.Create], Post);
      can([Action.Update, Action.Delete], Post, { authorId: { $eq: user.id } });
    }

    if (user.role === UserRole.MODERATOR) {
      // Additional permissions for moderators on top of verified user permissions
      can([Action.Update], Post);
      can([Action.Create], ActionVote);
}

    if (user.role === UserRole.ADMIN) {
      // Admins can do anything, overriding all previous permissions
      can(Action.Manage, 'all');
    }

    return build({
      // Read https://casl.js.org/v6/en/guide/subject-type-detection#use-classes-as-subject-types for details
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
        conditionsMatcher
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: PureAbility is not preconfigured. Use `createMongoAbility` or `Ability` class

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi Thank you for your comment. Seems like `Ability` is no longer in CASL package. I tried with `createMongoAbility` but the result didn't change. Added my code in the `UPDATE` section above. Would you mind taking a glance if there's any issue with that?

Comment: Too little details. I don’t see what `User` is and how do you do a check. I believe you do a mistake somewhere in TypeORM or nests config. What error do you get?

Comment: I’m the author of casl, and can tell you for sure Ability is not removed, it’s deprecated)

Comment: Can you follow debugging article from docs and check what rule you get for you specific check?  https://casl.js.org/v6/en/advanced/debugging-testing#debugging

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi Thank you for your time! I don't get any error now. Just a user is now able to edit a post from another user (which is not desired). Sure, I will follow the debugging tutorial and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: I had the same problem, and after trying out alot of things, i found that the ability.can or cannot needs to be passed the object itself as well not just the class name, and the condition on the rule _id: user._id only matches if the supplied object and the user object both have the ids converted to string as mongoose ObjectId cannot be matched with simple ===, as of now i am moving forward with this, I had to add the authorization logic in the controller, let me know if there is a better way